# Ai/Computer player for a simple Pong Game

Tags: java

Ok, Ive just finished writing my pong game, but now I want an AI for players to play against.
Ive tried doing this by making it so that, when the location of the NPC padel is more than the Y co-ords of the ball, it moves to the right area to try and block the ball.
Here is the code for my padel Class:

```
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


public class Padel implements KeyListener{
    private Ball ball = new Ball();
    private boolean LeftPlayerUp=false;
    private boolean LeftPlayerDown=false;
    private boolean RightPlayerUp=false;
    private boolean RightPlayerDown=false;
    public int RightLocation=200;
    public int LeftLocation=200;

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int KeyPressed = e.getKeyCode();

        if (KeyPressed== KeyEvent.VK_W){
            LeftPlayerUp=true;
        }
        else if (KeyPressed==KeyEvent.VK_S){
            LeftPlayerDown=true;
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int KeyReleased = e.getKeyCode();

        if (KeyReleased== KeyEvent.VK_W){
            LeftPlayerUp=false;
        }
        else if (KeyReleased==KeyEvent.VK_S){
            LeftPlayerDown=false;
        }
    }
    public void ShouldLeftMove(){
        if(LeftPlayerUp==true){
            if(LeftLocation==50){}
            else{
                LeftLocation-=2;
            }
        }
        else if(LeftPlayerDown==true){
            if(LeftLocation==Main.Height-190){}
            else{
            LeftLocation+=2;
            }
        }
    }   
    public void ShouldRightMove(){
        if(ball.BallLocationY>=RightLocation){
            RightPlayerUp=false;
            RightPlayerDown=true;
        }else{
            RightPlayerUp=true;
            RightPlayerDown=false;
        }
        if(RightPlayerUp==true){
            if(RightLocation==50){}
            else{
            RightLocation-=2;
            }
        }
        else if(RightPlayerDown==true){
            if(RightLocation==Main.Height-190){}
            else{
            RightLocation+=2;
            }
        }
    }   
    //This just needs to be here :P
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

With this code the padel goes to about 2/3rds down the screen on the right side, then just stops moving and spaz's out.
What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly accounting for the size of the paddle and offsetting appropriately?

Comment: Im accounting for the size I belive, unless im thinking of the way it works incorrectly. Does no-one else have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't spotted your exact problem, and with just a little snippet of code I can't run it and see the problem, but I do have some advice for you.

First, everywhere you check limits, you check for the exact condition.  If the location ever somehow gets set to an odd value, or ever somehow jumps past the limit, your limit code won't handle it.  I suggest that instead of

```
    if(LeftPlayerUp==true){
        if(LeftLocation==50){}
        else{
            LeftLocation-=2;
        }
    }
```

you should use

```
    if (LeftPlayerUp) {
        if (LeftLocation <= 50) {
            LeftLocation = 50;
        }
        else {
            LeftLocation-=2;
        }
    }
```

This way, if LeftLocation ever gets a whacked-out insane value, it will simply be corrected.  Use this pattern everywhere you check a limit.

My other bit of advice is that your computer player algorithm is very simple.  It doesn't take into account the direction the ball is moving.  If the ball is above the right paddle, but moving downward, maybe the right paddle shouldn't move... now, you don't want the computer player to play perfectly all the time, because that won't be fun for the human who can only lose; but you should start out with a perfect computer player.  The best way to do it is to just calculate where the ball will cross the line of the right paddle.  Your game knows the current position of the ball, and the speed with which it will go both right and up/down, so your game can predict where the ball will go; you could even simulate the whole trajectory of the ball including bounces and compute exactly where the ball will go.  Then make the computer player move the paddle toward that spot.  Once you have the perfect computer AI working, then add random mistakes, or simplify it (like take out the code that handles bounces; maybe the way to beat the AI is always to bounce the ball off a wall!).

Good luck and have fun.